# SSIS Lookup by NVarChar(Max) Column

Tags: ssis

I want to get id from target table by lookup with NVarChar(Max) column in target table and NVarChar(20) column in source table. But raise error `Cannot map the lookup column, 'Column1', because the column data type is a binary large object block (BLOB).`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you cant:

> The join can be a composite join, which means that you can join
>   multiple columns in the transformation input to columns in the
>   reference dataset. The transformation supports join columns with any
>   data type, except for DT_R4, DT_R8, DT_TEXT, DT_NTEXT, or DT_IMAGE

are you sure you are using the component correctly? You usually lookup by ID to get the text.
Can you give more details?

Answer (score 4):

In your Lookup transformation, you need to cast the blob (nvarchar(max)) to a non-blob type. In this case, I would assume you need to cast it to nvarchar(20).

You will need to write a query in the lookup transformation and not just select the table.

Assuming the lookup table looks like

```
LookupTable
--------------
Column0 int
Column1 nvarchar(max)
Column2 nvarchar(500)
```

You query would look like

```
SELECT 
    L.Column0
,   CAST(L.Column1 AS nvarchar(20)) AS Column1
,   L.Column2 
FROM
    dbo.LookupTable L
```

You should now be able to perform a lookup on that column.