# BLOB error when mapping nvarchar columns with the same fixed length in SSIS

Tags: ssis

I am using SSIS to move data between environments, and I am getting the following error quite often inside Lookup components, when mapping the input columns to the output columns:

[image]

I fixed the problem in most locations, and using nvarchar(MAX) as the type was the cause of the problem, but I am still getting it, even when the type of the input and output columns is nvarchar(100). Any idea why I am getting this error? I tried to use a data conversion on the source data before, but without any success!

**EDIT**

Below you can find screenshots from my lookup's configuration (named lookup update rows)

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image: And thhis happens when I drag "PaymentNature" and "PieceTypeDisplay" to its corresponding mappings]

[image]

**EDIT 2**

When I open the .dtsx file related with the project in a text editor, I have several datatypes set as **nText** (like shown below), which I think is the cause of my problem.

```
dataType="nText"

cachedDataType="nText"
```

I change these lines to, respectively, the following lines:

```
dataType="wstr"
length="100"

cachedDataType="wstr"
cachedLength="100"
```

But when I build, my changes disappear, and the **ntext** types are once again set.

Comment: Probably you overlooked something.   Can you post screenshots of the lookup and what you did to convert that column to a non-BLOB?

Comment: @TabAlleman I added the screenshots to the question. I have this problem in different places of my package, and I think I did nothing to convert that column to a non-BLOB. Maybe I dropped the destination table, and recreated it with a different type, changing only the size of the varchar

Comment: Possible duplicate of [SSIS Lookup by NVarChar(Max) Column](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10860644/ssis-lookup-by-nvarcharmax-column)

Comment: I don't know why my answer isn't working for you, it turns out to be identical to other answers given on this site, so I will mark as duplicate.   There could be something else in your package causing it not to work, but the answer in the duplicate question is the correct answer to your question.

Comment: @TabAlleman I don't think it's a duplicate. In that question, the author specifically states that he's using nvarchar(max), and that's not my case! I will add further information to the question in a second EDIT, since I tried a different approach

Comment: @TabAlleman I found the problem. Check my answer please!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution to get rid of BLOB types is to change the datatypes (SSIS datatypes) for the components within the dataflow in the advanced editor.

1. For each component, right click on it, and choose "Show advanced
   editor"
2. Click in the column "Input and output properties"
3. For all the input and output columns listed there, change the datatype when it is **DT_NEXT** to **DT_WSTR**, choosing an appropriate length as well

[image]

Comment: That's why I wanted to see the Advanced tab.  I forgot that it was actually in the Advanced Editor.

Answer (score 0):

This didn't work for me as I was using an ODBC data source.

I had to CAST my blob table fields as varchar(max) using the SQL command text box in the ODBC Source Editor and then go to the advanced editor and edit all ODBC source Output columns that I had CAST as DataType string[DT_STR].

Hope this helps someone.

Answer (score 0):

What solved my problem is that my source had string constraint of 50 chars while my destination was varchar(max). I changed to metadata in the destination column that was giving me the error from max to 50. Problem solved.